# gmaps4rails map artefact above the zoom slider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am displaying the map, but get some sort of an [artefact](http://grab.by/BasW) above the zoom slider.

Anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: Now that I saw a zoomed version of the issue in the shared screenshot, it seems to be a distorted multiple of the street view 'person'.

Comment: please check css topics while using google maps + some css framework

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @apneadiving! One of the first Google search results brought me to a [solution](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/173-google-map-css-issue). It was as simple as adding a:

```
max-width: none;
```

to the map `div`.